# Which alexa smart home skill interface should be implemented to support "open xxx" command?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

We'd like to support "open curtain" command in our smart home skill. Alexa always responds "xxx doesn't support that".

Which smart home skill interface should we implement to support that? Read through the [smart home skill docs](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/understand-the-smart-home-skill-api.html) but find no clue.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Alexa Smart Home Skill doesn't Support that. You need to use the custom skill if you want to say open curtain or any other intents which are not available in the Smart Home skill.

PowerController Interface only uses Turn on and turn off. However, for time being you can assign it for the curtain. They are gonna bring the update in the future for open and many more custom intent in the Smart Home Skill API.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using the PowerController and PowerLevelController APIs to control a curtain with a Particle.io Photon running the latest Patriot code. Alexa responds to "open" and "close" as well as percent commands.

Based on the above response, I'm guessing that Amazon added support in the past couple years. I've only been using the curtain controller for the past month so I can't be sure.